# Probability of selection without replacement and dependent removal

Tags: probability

Suppose my friend has a bag with 3 green marbles and 2 red marbles. I take out a single marble at random and put it aside. If the marble I take out is green, then my friend takes out a single red marble at random and puts it aside. I then take out another single marble at random from the remaining marbles in the bag. What is the probability that I take out 2 green marbles?

Suppose I label the marbles in the bag: g1, g2, g3, r1, r2. I then have the following possible outcomes:

```
g1 is taken out, then r1 is taken out, then g2 is taken out
g1 is taken out, then r1 is taken out, then g3 is taken out
g1 is taken out, then r1 is taken out, then r2 is taken out

g2 is taken out, then r1 is taken out, then g1 is taken out
g2 is taken out, then r1 is taken out, then g3 is taken out
g2 is taken out, then r1 is taken out, then r2 is taken out

g3 is taken out, then r1 is taken out, then g1 is taken out
g3 is taken out, then r1 is taken out, then g2 is taken out
g3 is taken out, then r1 is taken out, then r2 is taken out

g1 is taken out, then r2 is taken out, then g2 is taken out
g1 is taken out, then r2 is taken out, then g3 is taken out
g1 is taken out, then r2 is taken out, then r1 is taken out

g2 is taken out, then r2 is taken out, then g1 is taken out
g2 is taken out, then r2 is taken out, then g3 is taken out
g2 is taken out, then r2 is taken out, then r1 is taken out

g3 is taken out, then r2 is taken out, then g1 is taken out
g3 is taken out, then r2 is taken out, then g2 is taken out
g3 is taken out, then r2 is taken out, then r1 is taken out

r1 is taken out, then g1 is taken out
r1 is taken out, then g2 is taken out
r1 is taken out, then g3 is taken out
r1 is taken out, then r2 is taken out

r2 is taken out, then g1 is taken out
r2 is taken out, then g2 is taken out
r2 is taken out, then g3 is taken out
r2 is taken out, then r1 is taken out
```

I count 26 possible outcomes. 12 of these result in 2 green marbles being taken out. I would therefore conclude that the probability of taking out 2 green marbles is 12/26 or 6/13.

However, I have read the following statement:

> Two events that happen sequentially are not always independent. The
>   occurrence of one event may affect the occurrence of a following
>   event. In that case, the probability that both events happen is equal
>   to the probability that the first event happens multiplied by the
>   probability that given that the first event has already happened, the
>   second event happens as well.

I would say that the probability of first taking out a green marble is 3/5. Given that I have taken out a green marble, the probability that I take out another green marble is 2/3. I would therefore conclude from this statement that the probability of taking out 2 green marbles is (3/5)*(2/3) = 6/15.

These two approaches give different results. What have I missed?

Comment: The second method and answer are correct.

Comment: Why? What I have missed in the first approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method and answer are correct.

The $26$ possibilities in your list are not equally likely. So we cannot simply count and divide.

For example, $(g_1, r_1, g_2)$ has probability $(1/5)(1/2)(1/3)$ while $(r_2,g_1)$ has probability $(1/5)(1/4)$.

Comment: Why are they not equally likely? What would the list of the equally likely possibilities be?

Comment: Why would $r_{1}$ in the first set have probability (1/4) and not (1/2)?

Comment: Why would $r_1$ $\dots$? Because when we have taken out $g_1$, there are $4$ balls left, and $r_1$ is one of them. Later your list has $g_1$ then $r_2$.

Comment: Maybe I have worded the question too vaguely. My friend looks in the bag, and chooses one of the 2 red marbles to remove. So he isn't choosing from 4, he is choosing from 2.

Comment: @user695931: Yes, I misinterpreted, the second is $1/2$. That changes the probabilities (and I have edited) but it does not change the fact they are not all the same.

Comment: Would you mind listing the equally likely possibilities? It might help clarify this for me.

Comment: Because of the forced removal of a red if the first is green, there is no natural division into equally likely cases.

Comment: I'm surprised. I would have guessed that all probability questions involving finite possibilities could be reduced to doing so. How do we know the second approaches holds then?

Comment: The reasoning of the second approach is a clean conditional probability calculation that closely mirrors the description of the experiment. As to finite discrete, if probabilities are not commensurable then we cannot reduce to equally likely outcomes. In our case, the following might work. Take out all five marbles one at a time, with a forced red on the second pick

Comment: Do you know where I can find a proof of the statement that I quoted?

Comment: What statement did you quote? If you are referring to your second calculation, you could think of it as using $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A\mid B)\Pr(B)$, which is the definition of conditional probability.

Comment: So $Pr(A \cap B)$ would be the probability of selecting a green marble on both the first draw and the second draw, $Pr(A | B)$ would be the probability of selecting a green marble on the second draw given that a green marble was selected on the first draw, and $Pr(B)$ would be the probability of selecting a green marble on the first draw? This is a definition? It is not derived somehow from the definition of $Pr(E)$ as the number of outcomes in the event $E$ divided by the number of possible outcomes in the experiment?

Comment: Formally, it is a definition. Informally, it is justified by restricting the sample space to the part where $B$ occurs.